# Material type css input label overlapping auto fill, not activating until an action - Angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular, input, material-design

I'm using a material style input , but when there is an auto fill its overlapping the values in it, tried different ways like input:valid , input:enabled etc. is there any way to get it done, the development is in **angular 2**

code below

```
 <form  ngNativeValidate class="pop-form" (submit)="signIn()" >
    <div class="group">
      <input type="text" name="user" [(ngModel)]="credentials.email" class="form-control" placeholder="&nbsp;" required="">
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <label >E-mail</label>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <input type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="credentials.password" class="form-control" placeholder="&nbsp;" required="" >
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label >Password</label>
</div>

      <div [class.loader]="signingIn" ></div>
    <button type="submit" name="login" class="bt-login">LOG IN</button>
    <button class="bt-login clickable" (click)="register()" >CHECK IN</button>
</form>
```

Css

```
.login-box .group {position:relative; margin-bottom:15px;}
.login-box input{font-size:18px;padding:15px 10px 10px 5px;display:block;width:100%;border:none;border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC; box-shadow: none;border-radius: 0;height: 48px;}
.login-box input:focus{ outline:none; box-shadow: none;}
.login-box input[type="checkbox"]{display: inline-block;}
.login-box label{color: #646464;font-size: 20px;font-weight: 600;position:absolute;pointer-events:none;left:10px;top:10px;transition:0.2s ease all; -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;}
.login-box input:focus ~ label, input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label , input:valid ~ label{top:-5px;font-size:13px;color:#646464;font-weight: 300;left:3px}
.login-box .bar{ position:relative; display:block; width:100%; }
.login-box .bar:before, .bar:after{content:'';height:2px;width:0;bottom:0px;position:absolute;background:#646464;transition:0.45s ease all;-moz-transition:0.45s ease all;-webkit-transition:0.45s ease all;z-index: 999;}
.login-box .bar:before {left:50%;}
.login-box .bar:after {right:50%; }
.login-box input:focus ~ .bar:before, input:focus ~ .bar:after {width:50%;}
.login-box input:focus ~ .highlight {-webkit-animation:inputHighlighter 0.45s ease;-moz-animation:inputHighlighter 0.45s ease;animation:inputHighlighter 0.45s ease;}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done it with 
**input:-webkit-autofill:focus ~ label** in my case
changing the css to

```
.login-box input:focus ~ label, input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label , input:valid ~ label, input:-webkit-autofill:focus ~ label{top:-5px;font-size:13px;color:#646464;font-weight: 300;left:3px}
```

solved it

Comment: it dealt with the overlapping of the autofilled email and label, but if there is no email then the label stays at the top, but it should get back into the input